# Tunnel only specific folder/directory with ngrok

Tags: localhost

I want to tunnel only 1 folder/directory. Can I achieve this with ngrok?

I'm using xampp and most of my projects are WordPress websites.

I don't want the person with the link to see all my other folders.

Basically I'm using ngrok to show the projects to my clients and I want to show only specific folders.

Comment: Create a virtual host for your single WordPress site and proxy that instead.

Comment: Can you provide more details? How can I create a virtual host only for 1 wordpress site?

Answer (score -1):

This is quite late for you, but this might help others.

I came across this same situation and I found the way.

Basically you need to create virtual host as @TheDeadMedic have suggested and then you can use it for ngrok.

I found this tutorial for wamp, so you can get idea for XAMPP from it.

https://john-dugan.com/wamp-vhost-setup/

P.S. I'm not promoting this tutorial.